# Are there any Hogwarts students who live in Hogsmeade during the summer?

Tags: harry-potter

Hogsmeade has a lot of individuals who live there, and it has the distinction of being the only non-muggle community in the UK. Are there any students at Hogwarts who live there during the summer?

I ask because [the Pottermore article on the Hogwarts Express](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/the-hogwarts-express) explicitly says that students must ride the train or not go to the school at all, which seems silly for someone who already lives at the destination.

> Many pure-blood families were outraged at the idea of their children using Muggle transport, which they claimed was unsafe, insanitary and demeaning; however, as the Ministry decreed that students either rode the train or did not attend school, the objections were swiftly silenced.

Comment: It seems obvious that there must be student families in Hogsmeade, and just as obvious that they wouldn't need to take the train... but yeah, little weird how that never came up.  Blame the need to treat it as a tourist trap?

Comment: Possible dupe of [How do children from Hogsmeade come to Hogwarts?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111012/how-do-children-from-hogsmeade-come-to-hogwarts?) by exclusion. **None of the answers mention any kids living in Hogsmeade**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do children from Hogsmeade come to Hogwarts?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/111012/how-do-children-from-hogsmeade-come-to-hogwarts)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### There probably are. We don't hear anything about them, though.

We know that there are people who live in Hogsmeade. There are plenty of cottages dotted around in the village.

> Hogsmeade looked like a Christmas card; **the little thatched cottages** and shops were all covered in a layer of crisp snow; there were holly wreaths on the doors and strings of enchanted candles hanging in the trees.
>   <sub>*(Prisoner of Azkaban, Chapter 10, The Marauder's Map)*.</sub>
>
> Harry had never been in this direction before. The winding lane was leading them out into the wild countryside around Hogsmeade. The **cottages** were fewer here, and their gardens larger; they were walking toward the foot of the mountain in whose shadow Hogsmeade lay.
>   <sub>*(Goblet of Fire, Chapter 27, Padfoot Returns)*.</sub>

The people who live there are described as the "residents of Hogsmeade". Presumably, there are quite a few of them since Hogsmeade is the only non-Muggle settlement in Britain.

> Voldemort’s voice reverberated from the walls and floor, and Harry realized that he was talking to Hogwarts and to all the surrounding area, that the **residents of Hogsmeade** and all those still fighting in the castle would hear him as clearly as if he stood beside them, his breath on the back of their necks, a deathblow away.
>   <sub>*(Deathly Hallows, Chapter 33, The Prince's Tale)*.</sub>

Hogwarts kids who live in the village don't feature at all, if they exist. On the balance of probabilities, at least some of the residents of Hogsmeade must have children. Those children need schooling. Why wouldn't the parents send their kids to Hogwarts since it lies on their doorstep? The chances are that there are Hogwarts children who live in Hogsmeade. If we stick strictly to canon, however, we can't say one way or the other.

As for the method of transportation, we know that most people at least use the Hogwarts Express. When almost everyone went home for the Christmas holidays in *Chamber of Secrets* it was the Hogwarts Express that they used.

> There was almost a stampede to book seats on the Hogwarts Express so that students could go home for Christmas.
>   <sub>*(Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 12, The Polyjuice Potion)*.</sub>

Does that mean that it's forbidden for people to walk to Hogwarts from the village? Hardly. As [Moogle points out](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/111016/64888) on another question, Harry walks to the school from Hogsmeade in *Half-Blood Prince*. The restrictions in the Pottermore article on the Hogwarts Express refer to people from *outside* the area wanting to get to Hogwarts through other means. The point of the embargo was to stop people from breaking of the Statute of Secrecy by using brooms or other means of transport en masse. People coming from England, for instance, *had* to use the train. Kids living in Hogsmeade could presumably just walk over to the train station and join up with everyone else there. As long as Hagrid has all the first-years in one place for the boat trip there is no logistical reason why those students could not walk to the train station rather than catching the Hogwarts Express. Older students living in Hogsmeade could just get in a Thestral-drawn carriage and wait for their friends to turn up. I don't think that the Ministry guidelines about the Hogwarts Express were designed to stop people who lived within walking distance of the station taking the most logical mode of transport to get there.

Comment: “The point of the embargo was to stop people from breaking the Statute of Secrecy.” If we assume they would break the Statute to travel to Hogwarts, why shouldn’t we assume they would break the Statute to travel to London just as well? There are no Muggles near Hogwarts, yet London is a large, Muggle-filled city. Of those two places London seems by far the worst place to have the entire wizard population converge twice a year.

Comment: @11684 Yes but part of the point of picking a prominent Muggle location was that wizards and witches travelling into it would be forced to adopt some form of disguise or to fit in with the Muggle population. That's not to say that people wouldn't use magic to get there, as the Weasleys did with their magically enlarged car. But the travel arrangements are necessarily discreet. There may be the odd person who shamelessly breaks the Statute, whether travelling directly or via London. But by breaking it in central London in plain view of Ministry officials they were guaranteeing that they'd be...

Comment: @11684 ...caught and reprimanded. Most people wouldn't want that and would fall into line. Those who break the rules face the consequences. Pretty quickly everyone follows the rules and catches the train whilst hiding their magic. As I say in the answer, though, I don't think that would've stopped kids from Hogsmeade from walking up the road to Hogwarts.